# Setup a Default Project by user when uploading multiple documents to the document library

Tags: 2010, document-library

We use Sharepoint mainly to track / store documents on our document library. We have several members uploading documents daily for different projects.

Our problem is that, every time a document is uploaded, the user needs to manually edit document properties and change the project.

Would it be possible to set a default project for each user, especially when uploading multiple documents?

If so, does it require any special / managerial grant on Sharepoint? Also, how and where to change this option?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an event receiver for this document library and in "Item Adding" event get user who upload document and auto populate project field.

Comment: Heads-up for ItemAdding not firing when creating a new document from inside of SharePoint. In that case use ItemUpdating

Comment: Any user can create his own events or it needs a kind of special grant (i.e. it needs to be done programmatically)?

Comment: Need to be done programmatically.

Comment: Checking [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231563.aspx), it seems I'd need to hard code the default project for each member... I thought Sharepoint would offer a more straightforward way to handle it :(

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways to add default values of metadata

- Use an [event receivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231563.aspx)
- Use **Column default Value** settings. This options is often forgotten.
  Create a few folders in the library and go to **Library Settings > Column default value** settings option. Select one of the created folders and set default of one of the managed fields
- Use [DocumentSets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg581064%28v=office.14%29.aspx) and inherit values of the document set

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently struggling with my SP managers to have the library settings activated. Even the project owners don't have these settings enabled.